# Sharepoint online (Office 365) : CEWP

Tags: html, sharepoint, office365, cewp

While trying to provide Content Link for CEWP to a html file/text file, I am getting error **"Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the Content Link property. For more assistance, contact your site administrator."** On clicking the "Test Link" button, the page opens in a new page. I have tried the following, but not resolved.

- I have tried on moving the file to shared documents.
- I have changed the extension .html to .txt
- Confirmed that, logged in user has permission

Kindly share suggestions or way to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using relative path. Specify absolute path to file. Sometimes it is only way to resolve similar issues.
Do you have any whitespaces in url? If yes then replace it with %20. May be it is your case.
Is file located in same site collection? If no then locate it in current site collection.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Vsevolod. Tried both relative and absolute path and there is no whitespaces in URL.